# Two Access queries, removing duplicate record base on a value

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have two queries, qFabricate01 and qFabricate02, with the only difference is in the field labeled Fabricate.  In q01 I am using the date value from the field Delivery and q02 the date value from the field PUDATE.  What I would like to do is combine the two, removing the duplicate row, of the line item that contains the Fabricate date in the future.

Ex  on these two orders I would only want the two line items that had Fabricate dates of 8/14 and 8/16

Fabricate     Delivery      PUDate       COMMs

08/16/2012  08/16/2012  08/22/2012 T041317

08/22/2012  08/16/2012  08/22/2012 T041317

08/23/2012  08/23/2012  08/14/2012 T045118

08/14/2012  08/23/2012  08/14/2012 T045118

SELECT qOracleOpenOrders.Delivery AS Fabricate, qOracleOpenOrders.Delivery, qOracleOpenOrders.Confirmed, qOracleOpenOrders.EntryDate, qOracleOpenOrders.COMMs, qOracleOpenOrders.BuilderKey, qOracleOpenOrders.Room, qOracleOpenOrders.Status, qOracleOpenOrders.PUDate, qOracleOpenOrders.ESO, qOracleOpenOrders.Market, qOracleOpenOrders.Material, qOracleOpenOrders.ID, qOracleOpenOrders.Comments, qOracleOpenOrders.Requested, qOracleOpenOrders.Remake, qOracleOpenOrders.LTFAB, qOracleOpenOrders.LTJSD, qOracleOpenOrders.Due
FROM qOracleOpenOrders;

Comment: Holy cow, table aliases.  `Select q.Due From qOracleOpenOrders q`.

Comment: Unnecessary comment - deleted

Answer (score 0):

OK So you've only got 2 rows right? One for each of the item numbers? & The reason you've got 4 rows is because of the queries you've got? Rather than combining the 2 queries, I think the answer is simply to write a single query which decides which value out of Delivery & PUDate to show as "Fabricate":

```
SELECT iif(Delivery > Date(), PUDate, Delivery) AS Fabricate, ... (other columns) 
FROM qOracleOpenOrders
[WHERE ...]
```

Does this help?